# How to retrieve uploaded file in mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This is my controller code for uploading file , it is only storing the title in the database and actual file is stored in the documents/file folder now. I am facing problem in retrieving this uploaded file since I have stored only the title in database. How do I retrieve a file ?

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult UploadFile(string Title)
    {
        _Db.Uploads.Add(new Upload() { Title = Title });
        _Db.SaveChanges();

        int Id = (from a in _Db.Uploads select a.Upload_id).Max();
        if(Id>0)
        {
            if(Request.Files["file"].ContentLength>0)
            {
                string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(Request.Files["file"].FileName);
                string path1 = String.Format("{0}/{1}{2}", Server.MapPath("~/documents/Files"), Id, extension);
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(path1))
                    System.IO.File.Delete(path1);
                Request.Files["file"].SaveAs(path1);
            }
            ViewData["Sucess"] = "success";
        }
        else
        {
            ViewData["Success"] = "Upload Failed";
        }

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Edit and format the question well.

Comment: you have to store relative path as well in the database

Answer (score 0):

> since I have stored only the title in database

```
 _Db.Uploads.Add(new Upload() { Title = Title });
 from a in _Db.Uploads select a.Upload_id
```

it appears you're also storing the ID, not just the title

The save path uses this ID.

```
string path1 = String.Format("{0}/{1}", Server.MapPath("~/documents/Files"), Id);
```

(I've removed the extension for now)

So simply read the file back using the ID of the file you want to reload:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult DownloadFile(int ID)
{
    string path1 = String.Format("{0}/{1}", Server.MapPath("~/documents/Files"), ID);
    return FilePathResult(path);
}
```

(otomh, untested)

Of course, the best solution is to persist the filename+extension (no need for path if it's always the same) with the title and ID.

**Edit**: More details:

You currently store the Title and ID, change this to also store the filename *path* `path1`.  Use this to retrieve the uploaded file.

Comment: sorry but actually didn't understand i m actually new for this field so plz can u explain in details   plzzzzzz

Comment: when i write this  return FilePathResult(path); it is showing error for me that it is type but is used like a variable